# How to remove data from numpy.memmap

Tags: python, numpy

I want to truncate file, created by `numpy.memmap`, so how can I remove data from `numpy.memmap`?

`memmap` usually used to reduce RAM consumption, but sometimes, when you work with really huge data, it's useful to save disk space too, so when you confident that нщг will not use data large chunk from `memmap`, it will be good idea to delete it from disk too.

How to do it?